# How can I show an additional replace option but not clutter the interface?

Tags: search

I have a search feature in an application and I want to add a replace feature, but I don't want to clutter the interface. Also, I only want to show the replace option after a user searches for something.

Flow:

- user enters keyword
- user hits enter or magnifying glass button
- results are displayed
- a "replace with" option appears

What should I do to achieve this?

Here's how the search looks now:

[image]

Comment: Is the proposed 'replace' feature a one-click option that replaces all instances of a phrase or can the user move forward and back through the instances and choose which to replace and which to ignore? I just wonder what controls the UI must support.

Comment: "replace all with ..." would be enough at this point

Comment: @Adrian Did you work this out yet? Seems like an interesting design challenge. Assuming the replacing will only be done to search results, the search results are key. Can you show what these look like?

Comment: I have an idea, but untested: use keywords in search field like "replace 'keyword' with 'keyword 2'". Needs a little education before using, but the interface remains light for those who don't use the feature.

Comment: @BobbyTables is this question still current (and if not could you close it out?)

Comment: Are there any other actions you want to do on the searched items? How are you currently showing the searched items (highlights vs a different UI for searched items)?

Answer (score 1):

I notice you have some icons underneath your search box. Why not add a link/icon there when a user enters the keyword? Then you are using the space already available and you won't need to add new things, so it still looks minimal and simple.

Comment: http://datasolutions.ro/adrian/img/2014-10-03_1753312312.png those belong to each result

Comment: Oh... do you have a screenshot of the whole screen?

Comment: @Adrian Productivity mode is off, so you could just bypass the search results entirely and head straight to YouTube videos of cats.

Answer (score 1):

Introducing a new object rather having the element there for this context users might miss the functionality and might require memorability and learn ability to recognize and interact, Hence the easier of doing this would be when a user enters the word to search, introduce a new icon which represent "replace" next to search icon, this would enable the users to easily understand that both these interactions can be done for the keyword that has been entered.

Also you can even throw some history to easily achieve the task.